# Spring Web Flow do nothing

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-webflow

I´m using Spring Web Flow but when I click submit button, it does not do anything; no errors, no exception, just redirect to the same page. Here is my code:

ConsultarControlOrdenAcunacionFlow.xml:

```
<view-state id="ConsultarControlOrdenAcunacion" model="ordenesAcunacionParaAutorizar">
    <binder>
        <binding property="ordenIds" required="true"></binding>            
        <binding property="comentario" required="true"></binding>            
    </binder>        
    <transition on="firmarOrdenes" to="GetDatosParaFirma" validate="false"/>
</view-state>
```

ConsultarControlOrdenAcunacion.jsp:

```
    <form:form id="formaAplicaAccion" modelAttribute="ordenesAcunacionParaAutorizar" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="POST" >
        <form:input path="ordenIds" id="ordenIds" type="hidden" name="ordenIds" value=""/>
        <form:input path="comentario" id="comentario" type="hidden" name="comentario" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="display" id="ordenes1" style="font-size: 12px;" >
        </table>
        <input style="display:none;" id="botonAutorizar" type="submit" name="_eventId_firmarOrdenes" value="Firmar Datos"/>
    </form:form>
```

Jquery code:

$("#formaAplicaAccion").submit();

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue.  I fixed it by adding a hidden element that has a name equal to the button name.  This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with using a plugin like Firebug to view the submitted request. I'm betting that the [JQuery form.submit() doesn't submit the button name](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-form-with-multiple-submit-buttons) `_eventId_firmarOrdenes` that tells Web Flow which transition to take.

A couple of additional tips: First, the `action=` is unnecessary in the `form:form` tag. I can't find an authoritative source right now, but WebFlow will provide the correct action value automatically if you omit `action=` altogether.

Second, `name` [is not a valid attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#spring-form.tld.input) for `form:input`. Also, normally you want to use `form:hidden` instead of `form:input` (see that same link for valid attributes).